# Looping inside a if block

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach

The following is common in any programming language.

```
  foreach(.....)
  {
         if(...)
           ....
  }
```

I wonder whether it is a good programming practice to use the following. I know it works, but it looks little bit untidy.

```
  if(....)
  {
        foreach(...)
        {
           ...
        }
 }
```

Iterating over a collection when some condition evaluates to true is the requirement. But I have never seen this in any kind of sample codes. In a nutshell, I have never noticed such in codes written by other people. But this works and gives me what I want. But I want to avoid writing a loop inside a if block.

Can someone point out an alternative to this ?

Comment: If a condition is true, then you want to do something to/with a collection? I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. Why would you think so?

Comment: These two have a different logic behind. Both valid but in the first one you execute an if inside a loop if you have some kind of processing logic for every item of the collection, in the second one you execute the loop only if an external condition is true

Comment: Nothing wrong at all!

Answer (score 0):

Either is perfectly fine, but of course you should use only the construct that *works*.

An `if` statement inside a `foreach` loop is often checking some property of each element being enumerated. In this case, you cannot swap the order of the statements, because you need to execute the `if` for each element.

For example:

```
foreach (Foo foo in fooCollection)
{
    if (foo.Name == "ignore me")
    {
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
}
```

On the other hand, it would be wasteful to check inside a loop a condition that is "invariant" for the loop. That is, one that always has the same result.

For example:

```
bool ignoreAllFoos = true;

foreach (Foo foo in fooCollection)
{
    if (ignoreAllFoos)
    {
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
}
```

That would (normally) be useless and inefficient. Why enumerate all of the elements if you're never going to process any of them? So in that case, you could (and should) put the `foreach` inside the `if`:

```
bool ignoreAllFoos = true;

if (!ignoreAllFoos)
{
    foreach (Foo foo in fooCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
    }
}
```

Of course, the above examples are completely contrived. But I hope that they illustrate the difference between having the `if` inside the `foreach` loop vs having the `foreach` loop inside the `if`. The two ways of writing the code really do *not* do the same thing, but they *are* both useful ways of writing code. It just depends on what behavior you actually want to have.